# The inexorable rise in 'I searched on the web but didn't get the proper idea about that'

Tags: discussion

Is someone charging for unique homework answers that will not be detected by the anti-plagiarism copy-detection scripts run by professors/TA's?  The number of questions asking for readily-Googleable information to be regurgitated, (and always explicitly stating that search engines have already been tried), has been rising for some time and I'm wondering now if some pay-per-answer script is spamming submitted questions around SO and elsewhere in an attempt to use contributors as answer-fodder.

Even if I'm wrong, and the posters are just bone-idle deadbeats, it's still pretty annoying:(

Comment: I think lazy people wanting their work done for them is far more likely than an elaborate SO rep farming scheme.

Comment: They're just saying they searched the web so people don't tell them to Google it. These people know they haven't tried enough to warrant an SO question and have probably had people tell them off for it before.

Comment: I'd agree that this statement is bogus most of the time (especially for low rep users). You might ask them for showing their research results, or simply send such question to the close voting queue (most of this stuff isn't stating an appropriate question for SO).

Comment: Today's random [example #1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626426/how-to-save-a-png-file-in-c), [example #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624515/need-help-w-arrays-in-c-programming-have-no-idea-what-to-do).

Comment: This is why we don't expect people to tell us *that* they've done research, rather we ask them to demonstrate the research that they've done.  Just claiming that you searched is not *demonstrating* research.

Comment: The really frustrating part is that somehow "doing research" and "I googled it" seem to have become synonymous.

Comment: The questions linked by @Jongware make me feel like an over-achiever. I normally search the web for at least a day, usually two before posting here. If I'd known just _stating_ I searched was a thing... I'd have far more questions!.. And less rep.

Comment: @Kendra Or much *more* rep. Some of the most easily google-able questions are upvoted through the roof because so many people have the same question.

Comment: Wow, that homework question is amazing.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You may have a point- Especially considering I at least would have an idea how to disguise such a poor question... I've easily BSed my way through essays and made it look like I did research before. If I can do that, then I could do the same for questions. But respect for the site and the help I've gotten here is rather high, so I'd rather not pollute.

Comment: @eddie_cat "These people know they haven't tried enough to warrant an SO qusetion" do they? if they're a new user, it's almost guaranteed that they **don't** know what warrants an SO question. To anyone but a fully initiated SO user, SO seems like the place you go to ask any question about programming, of any scope. They don't know that you are supposed to ask 10 people IRL, lurk in chatrooms for a month, and do 2 weeks of exhaustive google/bing/askjeeves searching first.

Comment: Hah, here's another example.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630357/unsolvable-java-lang-interruptedexception-in-a-java-code

Comment: @TylerH The three examples commented that I see all have prior questions. Granted, I don't see comments on the couple I looked at saying to show research, but those easily could've been deleted. Granted, you do have a point.

Comment: @TylerH normally when I see users say that they "looked online but it didn't help" or something like that are usually users who have posted previous questions and gotten "in trouble" for not researching. It's often a feeble attempt to show effort. If they had looked online they'd be explaining *why or how* whatever they found didn't work.

Comment: That homework question is indeed amazing. Every time I see a question and think "this has got to be the *worst question ever* and surely I'll never encounter a similar one", SO proves me wrong.

Comment: Ah, I forgot *yesterday's* [my code so far](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610469/simple-encryption-program-in-c). The third act of a story that may end in tears OR The Most Succesful New Application Of 2014. At the moment it can still go both ways.

Comment: Flip side: Those with higher reputation are now donning their nazi freeze'em uniforms and marking honestly relevant questions as either duplicates, off topic, too broad, or too narrowly focused; when they clearly aren't.  If we allow these two opposing vectors (bogus lazy squad and nazi close'em squad) to continue, we're going to lose this place.

Comment: @User.1: you win today's Godwin's Law award. If you wanted a constructive discussion, you just blew your chances.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ack ! I lose.  You are correct. And,,, no editing to cover my sins.

Comment: @daOnlyBG: Best part: that user asked the same question 4 hours earlier.

Comment: Serious question: is this thread supposed to be more of a rant thread (nothing wrong with those), or are people expected to come up with reasonable solutions?

Comment: Ever get the feeling that most 'unique' questions have already been asked on SO, and the majority of questions now can be answered by helping a person google subjects properly?

Comment: @User I seem to have lost or misplaced my Nazi freeze'em uniform. You say that you have seen it?

Comment: @CodyGray I used the "N" word ("Nazi"). I am now at zero credibility. Nobody will ever love me again. In fact, it's retroactive; after typing that word, nobody has ever loved me before. (This is accomplished via special internet quantum physics)